# Is Code refactoring make positive affect?

Tags: angularjs, refactoring

Ok, I recently write this code in angular:

```
var percentPaid=(creditAmount/amountExTax)*100);
percentPaid=commonService.getPrecisedValue(percentPaid);
```

Then on the creation of merge request code review, my team lead asked me that it's better to refactor these two lines of code in one line so I refactor code like this:

```
var percentPaid=commonService.getPrecisedValue((creditAmount/amountExTax)*100);
```

Is this made effect, Many people said it'll affect but how?

Comment: any programming code is compiled line by line. so if there are more line of code and number of variable it will take more memory. So Ideally less line of code will work fast.

Comment: I agreed with you but how if the complexity is the same.